# Running apache behind a home wireless router

Tags: apache-2.2, router

I am currently learning PHP/Apache/MySql. So I need to run some demo php pages on server. But I am not able to start the server. It is showing some message as attached. I using internet by a wireless router in our home. I got IP address 192.168.0.101. Please find the error and give some suggestions or workarounds.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that some other software on your PC is already listening on port 80 - so your web server could not bind to listening socket. The most simple case when this might occur is if you try to start web server twice.

Are there any other webservers installed on your machine (IIS maybe)? If yes then either stop them or (if you don't need them) uninstall them.

Also if you use Skype you might want to shutdown it at the moment you're starting the server. Skype may listen port 80 for internal purposes.